# Commit message template in TortoiseHG

Tags: templates, mercurial, tortoisesvn, commit, tortoisehg

I have a question about TortoiseHg.

My organization is transitioning from SVN to Mercurial.  The overwhelming majority of users use Tortoise to manage their repositories vs. the command line.  In TortoiseSVN, we are able to show the default log template using SVN properties (from the Subversion tab in the properties of the folder, as reached from the context menu).  In TortoiseHg, there is no such properties menu.  So is there a way to show a default commit message template?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I know is the **Copy message** button, which provides a list of the latest 10 commit messages for easy reusage.